# How Can I save Data using Soap Jquery in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to save data using soap **Jquery** with **C# WebMethod** But can not save data in **SQL Server** please help me how can I save data using **Soap jquery**.
I am using IDE **Visual Studio 2015**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    function SavePersonRecord() {  

        var Name = $.trim($('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val());  
        var LName = $.trim($('#<%=txtlname.ClientID %>').val());
        var Company = $.trim($('#<%=txtCompany.ClientID %>').val());    
        var Messege = "";           
        if (Name == '') {  
            Messege = "Can not Blank Name";
        }          
        if (LName == '') {  
            Messege += "Can not Blank Last Name";  
        }  
        if (Company == '') {
            Messege += " Company Name Can not Blank";
        }
        if (Messege.length == 0) {        
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                dataType: "json",  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                url: "Soap-Service.aspx/InsertPersonRecord",
                data: "{'FirstName':'" + Name + "', 'LastName':'" + LName + "','Company':'" + Company + "'}",
                success: function (Record) {  

                        $('#txtName').val();  
                        $('#txtlName').val();  
                        $('#txtCompany').val();

                    if (Record.d == true) {  

                        $('#Result').text("Your Record insert");  
                    }  
                    else {  
                        $('#Result').text("Your Record Not Insert");  
                    }  

                },  
                Error: function (textMsg) {  

                    $('#Result').text("Error: " + Error);  
                }  
            });  
        }  
        else {             
            $('#Result').html('');  
            $('#Result').html(Messege);  
        }  
        $('#Result').fadeIn();  
    }  
    </script>  





   <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="border: solid 2px Green;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: red; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt; text-align: center; font-family: Verdana;">Enter Employee Information</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>First Name:  
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text="" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Last Name:  
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Company  
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnInsertRecord" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClientClick="SavePersonRecord(); return false" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

[image]

Comment: How does this question get upvoted? Please describe your efforts and a specific problem.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Exactly what I was wondering, some code (any code you tried) would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, My code is running Well here is the Code There is some few Changes in web application

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                var Name = $('#txtname').val();
                var Contact = $('#txtcontact').val();
                //var body = $('#txtbody').val();
                if (Name != '' && Contact != '') {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Soap-Jquery.aspx/InsertData",
                        data: "{'EmpName':'" + Name + "','ConNo':'" + Contact + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var obj = data.d;
                            if (obj == 'true') {
                                $('#txtname').val('');
                                $('#txtcontact').val('');
                                //$('#txtbody').val('');
                                $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        },
                        //error: function (result) {
                        //    alert("Error");
                        //}
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert('Please enter all the fields')
                    return false;
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_add_payment" runat="server">
    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <section>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ribbon">Data Insert Using Jquery</button>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <div class="col-md-2">Enter Name</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtname" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">Enter Contact No</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontact" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact No"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtcontact" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed" ValidationExpression="\d+" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtcontact" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" value="Submit"  ValidationGroup="a" />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                
                <%--End Form Group--%>
            </div>
            <%--End Row--%>
        </div>
        <%--End Container--%>
    </section>    
    <br /><br /> 
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">


                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Width="100%">

                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ConNo" HeaderText="Number" />
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
                        
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</asp:Panel>
```

[WebMethod]
        public static string InsertData(string EmpName, string ConNo)
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insertEmp", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", EmpName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConNo", ConNo);
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    if (i == 1)
                    {

```
                    msg = "True";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "false";
                }

            }
        }

        return msg;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Vague question. However, do the following step:

1. Are you getting any error in browser console which breaks your javascript code?
2. Have you captured any error in "Error:" section?
3. If above both looks okay, have you put dubugger in your webmethod to check whether it gets hit or not?
4. After all this,is there in any server side exception (in your webmethod)?
5. Answer of 4) is yes, post the exception

Comment: No sir I am not getting any error but using debugger it shows the javascript error String is not JSON Formated

Comment: any problem here, just a wild guess?
 data: "{'FirstName':'" + Name + "', 'LastName':'" + LName + "','Company':'" + Company + "'}"

Comment: Sir Problem is shown here  URL: "Soap-Service.aspx/SaveUser",(String is not  JSON Formated)          the same script I am using another example it works fine but when I am Creating new web form project in visual studio 2015 then this problem is shown, I am sharing another script this script is also  shown same error but in another project Example it works Fine..

Answer (score 0):

Well as i can see you got problem with your ajax call. It should be:

```
      $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            dataType: "json",  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            url: "Soap-Service.aspx/SaveUser", //Here you got wrong method
            //right here you should pass object (not string) with right property names (like you have in your web method)
            data: { FName: Name, LNAme: LName, Company: Company},
            success: function (Record) {  
                $('#txtName').val();  
                $('#txtlName').val();  
                $('#txtCompany').val();

                if (Record.d == true) {  

                    $('#Result').text("Your Record insert");  
                }  
                else {  
                    $('#Result').text("Your Record Not Insert");  
                }  
            },  
            error: function (textMsg) {  
                $('#Result').text("Error: " + Error);  
            }  
        });
```

Above your webmethod you should add:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```